# How can we calculate the coordinates of multiple latitude and longitudes in miles and feet?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a array of latitudes and longitudes and I need to calculate the distance in miles and feet between the coordinates (In JavaScript or Typescript).

```
 const latsLngs = [
  {
    lat: 40.78340415946297,
    lng: -73.9714273888736,
  },
  {
    lat: 40.778399767985704,
    lng: -73.97915215083648,
  },
  {
    lat: 40.7722899997727,
    lng: -73.96842331477691,
  },
  {
    lat: 40.76617966968189,
    lng: -73.97769302913238,
  },
  {
    lat: 40.76838985393672,
    lng: -73.96147102901031,
  },
  {
    lat: 40.781909380720485,
    lng: -73.96636337825348,
  },
];
```

Comment: There's a lot of mathematics involved, so i'd suggest using a library to do the calculation for you (i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [geolib.getDistance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib), this will return distance in meters.

We can easily convert meters to miles and feet, knowing that there are 0.3048 meters in one foot and 5280 feet in a mile.

```js
const latsLngs = [ { lat: 40.78340415946297, lng: -73.9714273888736, }, { lat: 40.778399767985704, lng: -73.97915215083648, }, { lat: 40.7722899997727, lng: -73.96842331477691, }, { lat: 40.76617966968189, lng: -73.97769302913238, }, { lat: 40.76838985393672, lng: -73.96147102901031, }, { lat: 40.781909380720485, lng: -73.96636337825348, }, ]; 

function getDistanceInMilesAndFeet(a, b) {
    const distanceMeters = geolib.getDistance(a, b, 0.01);
    return metersToMilesAndFeet(distanceMeters);
}

function metersToMilesAndFeet(meters) {
    const totalFeet = meters / 0.3048;
    const miles = Math.floor(totalFeet / 5280);
    const feet = Math.round(totalFeet % 5280);
    return `${miles} miles, ${feet} feet`;
}

// Show distance from point 1 to the other points...
const a = latsLngs[0]; 
latsLngs.forEach((b, idx) => { 
    if (idx > 0) console.log(`Distance from point 1 to point ${idx + 1}:`, getDistanceInMilesAndFeet(a, b));
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/geolib@3.3.1/lib/index.js"></script>
```